# Convert BNF grammar to pyparsing

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing, bnf

How can I describe a grammar using regex (or pyparsing is better?) for a script languge presented below (Backus–Naur Form):

```
<root>   :=     <tree> | <leaves>
<tree>   :=     <group> [* <group>] 
<group>  :=     "{" <leaves> "}" | <leaf>;
<leaves> :=     {<leaf>;} leaf
<leaf>   :=     <name> = <expression>{;}

<name>          := <string_without_spaces_and_tabs>
<expression>    := <string_without_spaces_and_tabs>
```

Example of the script:

```
{
 stage = 3;
 some.param1 = [10, 20];
} *
{
 stage = 4;
 param3 = [100,150,200,250,300]
} *
 endparam = [0, 1]
```

I use python re.compile and want to divide everything in groups, something like this:

```
[ [ 'stage',       '3'],
  [ 'some.param1', '[10, 20]'] ],

[ ['stage',  '4'],
  ['param3', '[100,150,200,250,300]'] ],

[ ['endparam', '[0, 1]'] ]
```

**Updated:**
I've found out that pyparsing is much better solution instead of regex.

Comment: You can just reduce the grammar by substituting all non-terminal nodes to obtain a regex. However, what good would this do? The result would simply return a token stream for your input string, but would not preserve any structure, which is required to make semantic sense of the code.

Comment: There is an ABNF-to-regex converter here: http://www.a-k-r.org/abnf/

Comment: Also see this related Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898049/how-to-convert-a-regular-grammar-to-regular-expression

Comment: @AndersonGreen, ABNF-to-regex is very useful! thank you!

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yes, you are right and I'm thinking in pyparsing direction :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pyparsing lets you simplify some of these kinds of constructs

```
leaves :: {leaf} leaf
```

to just

```
OneOrMore(leaf)
```

So one form of your BNF in pyparsing will look something like:

```
from pyparsing import *

LBRACE,RBRACE,EQ,SEMI = map(Suppress, "{}=;")
name = Word(printables, excludeChars="{}=;")
expr = Word(printables, excludeChars="{}=;") | quotedString

leaf = Group(name + EQ + expr + SEMI)
group = Group(LBRACE + ZeroOrMore(leaf) + RBRACE) | leaf
tree = OneOrMore(group)
```

I added quotedString as an alternative expr, in case you wanted to have something that *did* include one of the excluded chars. And adding Group around leaf and group will maintain the bracing structure.

Unfortunately, your sample doesn't quite conform to this BNF:

1. spaces in `[10, 20]` and `[0, 1]` make them invalid exprs
2. some leafs do not have terminating `;`s
3. lone `*` characters - ???

This sample does parse successfully with the above parser:

```
sample = """
{
 stage = 3;
 some.param1 = [10,20];
}
{
 stage = 4;
 param3 = [100,150,200,250,300];
}
 endparam = [0,1];
 """

parsed = tree.parseString(sample)    
parsed.pprint()
```

Giving:

```
[[['stage', '3'], ['some.param1', '[10,20]']],
 [['stage', '4'], ['param3', '[100,150,200,250,300]']],
 ['endparam', '[0,1]']]
```